# Can we create a duplicate of our site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, duplicate

We have a SharePoint online classic team site which contain 60 sub-sites and 2 levels of sub-sites. and i want to create a copy of this site collection to use it as a test site. but i am not sure what are the available approaches we have within office 365 and SharePoint online to create a duplicate/copy of a site collection?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the site collection save as a template, then create a new site collection based on the custom template:
[image]
[image]

Or, you can use 3rd party tool to do that, like [it](https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004859227-Duplicate-Site-Collection).